# How to stream audios?

Tags: android, listview, media-player

I have listview, mediaplayer and mediacontroller. I'd like to make mediaplayer play stream musics from url when I touch list in listview. 
My problem is mediaplayer plays only one song. When I touch second list while playing first list audio, it does not play second list audio.
But I do not know the cause, mediaplayer plays second audio while playing first audio, when mediacontroller hides.
I want mediaplayer to stop and play another audio while mediacontroller shows and plays audio.
I tried two patterns, but these were same result.
Please teach me what is wrong and sorry bad english skill.
First pattern.

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
switch (position) {
case 0:
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(url);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
case 1:
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(url2);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
case 2:
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(url3);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
}
```

Second pattern.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(url[position]);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Preparedlistner.

```
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        controller.setEnabled(true);
                        controller.show(mp.getDuration());
                        mp.start();
                        try {
                            Method m = android.widget.MediaController.class.getDeclaredMethod("updatePausePlay");
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            m.invoke(controller);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

onCreate

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs);

        ItemBean sample1 = new ItemBean();
        fishing.setName("sample1");

        ItemBean sample2 = new ItemBean();
        hana.setName("sample2");

        ItemBean sample3 = new ItemBean();
        takane.setName("sample3");

        List<ItemBean> list = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
        list.add(sample1);
        list.add(sample2);
        list.add(sample3);

        sampleurl = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sampleurl);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        controller = new MediaController(this);
        controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.mediaController));
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        samplelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        SonglistAdapter_test adapter = new SonglistAdapter_test(getApplicationContext(),list);
        samplelist.setAdapter(adapter);

        samplelist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `mcontroller = new MediaController(context);` and doClean() somewhere? Most likely the controller needs to be reset before you put a new media source. Add this before your handler.post(new Runnable() {:

```
doClean();
mcontroller = new MediaController(getActivity());//or this, depending whats your context
```

Comment: Thankyou comment! I added onCreate code. `controller = new MediaController(this)`is in there. I tried putting `doClean();`in onCreate,but `doClean();` was red(Cannot resolve method).Also I got same message in onItemClickListner. Was I wrong place to put `doClean();`?